# Title possession in plaintext

Tags: possessives, titles

As far as I'm aware, titles are supposed to be italicised if Rich Text Formatting is available but wrapped in quotation marks if in a plaintext environment.

So, what is the correct way to show a title's possession in plaintext?

Consider the following example:

> *The 2nd Law*'s *Animals*

The following just doesn't seem right:

> "The 2nd Laws"'s "Animals"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a title's possession".

Comment: The obvious workaround is: *"Animals" from "The 2nd Law".*

Comment: @Matt Gutting Well, as per my example, an album has songs but the names of both are titles and should be formatted appropriately whilst also denoting possession.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't clear to me that one was a song title and the other an album title, nor where they stopped and started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MLA Handbook doesn't specify behavior here, and [this article](http://www.grammarunderground.com/plurals-and-possessives-of-movie-titles-in-quote-marks.html) seems to suggest other style guides don't either. In general, you should try to reword the sentence to not require such an awkward structure.